# Is there a way to expose "find" functionality in a node-webkit application?

Tags: node-webkit

Do I need to write my own find functionality to allow users to find text content on a page, or is there a way that node-webkit can expose pre-existing webkit find functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can do this in your app with some library like this: http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm

In current node-webkit there is no native UI to support this feature, but we'll see it in future if it has advantage.

Comment: Cool, I ended up implementing one myself quickly using a JQuery dialog and a couple of JQuery + underscore methods.